# VBA Excel Find child folder with DIR on UNC Path - Error with DIR

Tags: excel, loops, directory, unc, vba

this is my first time posting, sorry for any mistakes.

I'm trying to do a loop through server file folder (UNC Path) to find a specific child folder (project folder) to save the workbook (user will inform the project related to the folder).

I'm using a loop and DIR() function but for some reason DIR() returns "." for the first folder loop and for the second loop returns the first child folder.

```
StdPath = "\\Server\Database$\ABC\"

'Find project folder

Dirloop1 = Dir(StdPath, vbDirectory) 'Should return the 1st child folder, instead returns "."

'Loop into folders until find the project folder speficied by the user
Do Until Dirloop1 = ""
If (GetAttr(StdPath & Dirloop1) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
    Dirloop2 = Dir(StdPath & Dirloop1, vbDirectory) 'This should indicate the 2nd child folder but instead is returning the 1st child folder
    Do Until Dirloop2 = ""
        If (GetAttr(StdPath & Dirloop1 & Dirloop2) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then 'Error happens here since it didn't reach the second child folder
            If InStr(Dirloop2, ActiveSheet.Range("N7")) > 0 Then
                StdPath = StdPath & Dirloop1 & Dirloop2
                MsgBox StdPath
                Exit Do
            Else
                Dirloop2 = Dir()
            End If
        End If
    Loop
    If InStr(StdPath, ActiveSheet.Range("N7")) = 0 Then
        Exit Do
    End If

End If
Dirloop1 = Dir()
Loop
```

This is my first time using programming therefore doesn't have much experience if there's anyone who could give me a better solution I appreciate the support.

Comment: You should check for, and ignore, both "." and ".." being returned.

Comment: Do you mean to do a while statement with the DIR statement until returns the correct folder?

Comment: No, you just need an `If dirloop1 <> "." and dirloop1 <> ".." then` test before you start your subfolder search. And the same with `dirloop2`.

Comment: `Dir` can only hold one state simultaneously - you can't nest it like that.  Consider using the [Scripting.FileSystemObject](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/990/scripting-filesystemobject#t=201609131306588410183) instead. Also, the `.` ***is*** a (virtual) folder - it points to the parent directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rory and Comintern, thanks for the support, I finally managed to do it using FileSystemObject, much more easier than DIR() statement actually. I had to read about it first in order to implement it but the result was ok, code is below.

```
Public FSO As New FileSystemObject
Sub ProjectFolder()
Dim Dirloop as Folder
Dim Dirloop2 as Folder

StdPath = "\\Server\Database$\ABC\"

Set Dirloop = FSO.GetFolder(StdPath)

'Find Project Folder
For Each subfolder In Dirloop.SubFolders

Set Dirloop2 = FSO.GetFolder(subfolder.Path)

    For Each subfolder2 In Dirloop2.SubFolders
        If InStr(subfolder2.Path, ActiveSheet.Range("N7")) > 0 Then
            ProjectPath = subfolder2.Path
        End If
    Next
Next

If Len(ProjectPath) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Folder not found. Please talk with Project Leader"
    Exit Sub
End If
' Rest of the code below
```

Once again thanks for the help.